# MPI_Scatter 2d array different lengths

Tags: c, mpi

I'm new with MPI and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve,I have a 2D array of structs. The problem is that the 2D array is uneven and I dynamically created, for example:

```
1 1 1 1 1

2 2   2 2

3     3 3

4     4  

5
```

I want to send each column to one node, can this be done using Scatter? I have searched and I didn't found anything or I don't know what to search for, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's what `MPI_Scatterv` is for. But you need to flatten the 2D array and make it contiguous in memory, i.e., each column should immediately follow the previous one in memory, effectively forming a 1D array. Otherwise, you'll have to deal with arcane MPI user datatype hacks.

Comment: in that case, you could need `MPI_Scatterw()` which is not part of the MPI standard.